# adobe flex how to set registration point in <s:Group>

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
    <s:Group id="ellipse2">
        <s:Rect> 
            <s:stroke> 
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1"> 
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.5625"/> 
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.75"/> 
                </s:LinearGradientStroke> 
            </s:stroke> 
        </s:Rect>
        <s:Label id="label" text="Hello World" width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
    </s:Group>
```

Do I have to put this group into another group?, or there is a method to set the center point in the group?

Comment: When you ask "there is a method to set the center point in the group?" I don't understand which group you are referring to; ellipse2?  Or the group you want to put ellipse2 in?  I also don't understand what you mean by "setting the center point"

Answer (score 1):

You can put the group in another group by putting it in another group, like this.

```
<s:Group id="MyEllipseParentGroup">
    <s:Group id="ellipse2">
        <s:Rect> 
            <s:stroke> 
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1"> 
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.5625"/> 
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.75"/> 
                </s:LinearGradientStroke> 
            </s:stroke> 
        </s:Rect>
        <s:Label id="label" text="Hello World" width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

It can be positioned with the X and y properties, or by using a custom layout.

Comment: Great, be sure to mark it as the correct answer using the check to the left of the question.